# Attach Partition takes more time even after adding check constraint

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, check-constraints, postgresql-11, range-partitions

So basically we have a very large table in Postgres 11 DB which has hundreds of millions of data since the table was added. Now we are trying to convert it into a range based partition table based on `created_at` column (timestamp - ***not nullable***).

As suggested in the [Postgres Partitioning Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-partitioning.html), I tried adding a check constraint on the same table before actually running the attach partition. So after that if I run attach partition, ideally it should have taken very less time as it should skip the validation due to presence of respective constraint on the table, but I see it is still taking lot more time. My partition range and the constraint looks something like this:

```
alter table xyz_2020 add constraint temp_check check (created_at >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and created_at < '2021-01-01 00:00:00');
ALTER TABLE xyz ATTACH PARTITION xyz_2020 FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-01-01 00:00:00') TO ('2021-01-01 00:00:00');
```

Here `xyz_2020` is my existing big table which got renamed from `xyz`. And `xyz` is the new master table created like the old table. So I want to understand what could be the possible reasons that attach partition might still be taking lot more time.

**Edit:** We are creating a new partitioned table and trying to attach the old table as one of its partition.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Can you please show a complete reproducer, including both CREATE TABLE statements and whatever else is needed?